# Request to change default dialer isn't showing the system dialog using rolemanager

Tags: java, android

Here's my code and I have tried on real device as well as emulator but no success. I always get the toast failed to set default dialer without getting the popup.

```
private void setDefaultPhoneApp() {
    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> defaultDialerLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            result -> {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // The user successfully set this app as the default dialer
                    // TODO: Perform any necessary actions
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Default dialer set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    // The user did not set this app as the default dialer
                    // TODO: Handle this case
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to set default dialer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
    );

    RoleManager roleManager = getSystemService(RoleManager.class);
    if (roleManager.isRoleAvailable(RoleManager.ROLE_DIALER)) {
        if (!roleManager.isRoleHeld(RoleManager.ROLE_DIALER)) {
            Intent intent = roleManager.createRequestRoleIntent(RoleManager.ROLE_DIALER);
            defaultDialerLauncher.launch(intent);
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("Heere", "Setting the default dialer app is not supported on this device");
    }
}
```

My Permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ROLE_HOLDERS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_OWN_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ROLE_DIALER" />
```

Intent filters

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALL" />
    <data android:scheme="tel"/>
</intent-filter>
```

I was expecting a popup to show up asking the user to change and set the default dialer app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: I created a new app in android studio with min sdk 31, just to start fresh and added the following permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_OWN_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

and following intent filters in my main activity

```
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

and used below code to launch the system default popup to set default dialer

```
private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> setDefaultDialerLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            result -> {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // Check if your app is now the default dialer
                    if (roleManager.isRoleHeld(RoleManager.ROLE_DIALER)) {
                        // Your app is now the default dialer
                        Toast.makeText(this, "This app is now set as default dialer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //navigate to dashboard like screen here
                    } else {
                        // Your app is not the default dialer
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Please set this app as default calling app to proceed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    // Failed to set your app as the default dialer
                    Log.d("Dialer", "something went wrong while setting as default, most likely user cancelled the popup");
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please set this app as default calling app to proceed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
    );
Intent intent = roleManager.createRequestRoleIntent(RoleManager.ROLE_DIALER);
setDefaultDialerLauncher.launch(intent);
```

and it worked perfectly fine. Just don't forget to check with isRoleAvailable and isRoleHeld before executing this.
I still don't know what was the problem with the previous app so you are welcome to point out my mistake in previous app.
FYI previous app min sdk was 24.